# Cost for using GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator in Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-bucket

I am using GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator in Airflow v1 to load data from GCS Bucket files to GBQ tables. Previously we were using bq load command to perform this operation. The operator loads data in considerably less time. I would like to know what will be the cost involved in using this operator. bq load or GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator which will be a better option?

The amount of data that I am loading on a daily basis is around 2 to 3 TB.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Loading and exporting data to GCS from BQ is considered a free operation as mentioned in the [pricing document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free:~:text=maximum%20per%20organization)-,Free%20operations,-The%20following%20BigQuery). But, if you have a reservation assigned to load jobs too, then you will be paying for the load operation.

Comment: I am doing the other way around. from GCS to BQ. I believe it is free for this as well

Comment: Yess as you can see in the documentation